# Can an Object object be coerced into an Array object?

Tags: javascript

Crockford  writes in http://javascript.crockford.com/survey.html:
*"There are two ways to make a new array:


    var myArray = [];

    var myArray = new Array();"*

So I'm confused by these two lines in some AJAX code I am reading:

```
var obj={};    // obj is an Object object (i.e. a hash table)
obj[4] = 'x';  // now obj is suddenly an Array object via an integer key?
```

In JavaScript are an object and an array really just the same thing, but with a variant on the key type?

In other words, is this the same as in php where we can use *either* a name (string) or an integer for a hash key?

I've Googled for an answer on this but can't seem to nail down an article which discusses this issue.

One possibility that comes to mind is that perhaps the first line is syntactic lint because the 2nd line overwrites the previous definition of obj as it creates a new Array object.

Comment: So it appears that 4 is typecast into a string in this context.  Thank you Felix and agreco.

Comment: Even array keys are converted to strings because a property name (key/...) is always a string.

Comment: This is my first successful Q here and I was surprised by the quick and comprehensive responses.  Thank you to all who answered.

Comment: Don't forget to mark one of the answers as "accepted" by clicking the tick outline next to it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, no, an object can't be coerced into an array. *But*, it can look and act like an array, and that's what's happening here. Numbers, and anything else that can be coerced to a string, are perfectly valid property names for Javascript objects, so

```
obj[4] = 1;
obj['spam'] = 2;
```

are both valid ways of setting a property on the object. That doesn't make the object an array. An Array is a special class of object with specific methods (`.slice()`, `.concat()`, etc) and a `length` property that's kept up to date with the number of items in the array.

Answer (score 1):

it does not become an array, it is simply an Object with a '4' property, like this:

```
var obj = {
  '4': 'x'
};
```

it is just converted to a string when used as a property like `obj['4'] = 'x';`

Answer (score 1):

Everything but primitive datatypes is an object in JavaScript. Objects can have a properties and there are two ways to access object properties:

1. Dot notation, `foo.bar`, which you can use as long as the property name is a valid identifier.
2. Bracket notation, `foo['bar']` which you have to use if the key is not a [valid identifier *<sup>[spec]</sup>*](http://es5.github.com/#x7.6). For example, if it is a number, or contains a space or you have a variable with the name.

Hence, bracket notation is *not* a characteristic of arrays and if you see it, it does not mean the value is an array. It is simple one of two ways of accessing properties.

The elements of an array are just properties with numeric keys. Arrays are built on top of objects  and implement some additional methods which treat these numeric properties in a special way. For example the `.length` property is automatically updated when you add new elements. But ultimately they are just normal properties.

In your example you have a simple object. You have to access the property with `obj[4]` or `obj['4']` because `obj.4` is invalid since `4` is not a valid identifier (basically everything that you can use as variable name is a valid identifier. `var 4 = 'foo';` is invalid).

And since arrays are just objects, if you *could* use numbers as identifiers, you were also able to access an element with `arr.4`.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a loosely-typed, prototype-based language. Even primitive types like a boolean **can** be treated like an object ([though you aren't going to get far](http://jsfiddle.net/uaYvZ/1/)). Almost everything in javascript is, at root, an object.

Understanding this, an array IS an object. You can arbitrarily add properties to any object:

```
var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
xml[4] = 'x';
console.log(xml);
```

That object is still an instance of XMLHttpRequest. It now has a property labeled `4` with a value of `x`. You **can** treat anything like this -- even a function:

```
var test_func = function () {
    alert('woah!');
}
test_func[4] = 'x';
console.log(test_func[4]);
```

The take-away here is that the `obj[key] = value` notation is NOT indicative of an "array" type, like it is in languages such as PHP. Rather, it is an alternate way to access properties of any object, and is equivalent to `obj.key = value` (you can't use `obj.4 = 'x'`, though, that's invalid syntax). The other take-away is that any object in javascript can be modified or used in pretty much any way. You *shouldn't* misuse objects, but you *can*

Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/w2AqJ/

**Documentation**

- Array on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array
- *Javascript "associative arrays" considered harmful* by Andrew Dupont - http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/

Answer (score 0):

Yes

Javascript Array is very different from tradition array, you can think of it as object.

```
 var array = [1,2,3] is equivalent to var object = {'0' : 1, '1' : 2, '2' : 3}
```

except array inherited from Array.prototype and object inherited from Object.prototype, where Array.prototype will contain method such as length.

Comment: You forgot the length property of Arrays